# TS2339: Array.find in discriminated union not inferring type correctly

Tags: typescript

In this example I have a cart, which can be filled with different kinds of items, in this case its golfballs and golfclubs, which have their own options.

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?emitDecoratorMetadata=true&target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=45&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwDiCA2AzAIQEMccoBeKAbwFgAoKKUSALigCIBzXPAIxJzsA3PUYIwwAJYIAdgGc2tBoyhpcCOG3a8cKCOygAfDnAhIDx9gHcAFpOD6RygL5PX9es2jxk6LDwBhXV4KalEmcAgtbnw0YOFw8SlZBTDlRgA3IjhJIhlgLSszTn0jDjAUYAc4BJc3J09IqADs4ABJBwBbUJ9UDGx8YlIy3r8BvCCUXicvZtaOiE65UIBBODgiEAAeFrh2roA+Bro1eWBVVrZd-cXlygBtcKUVCNYOGL4BdgAacLEJaTyRR-FRqHAaLQ6PTsEHOcLOX7KZ4qLzRHhxKY-EFJQGpZEvLI5PIFDhFJAlGHpKBwlyIxj415Rd7o+J0lQ4lLAqmZbK5fJaCpVCA1WHw+gAXWOpzk5w+-GGlDQrQAdHhJDIkAAKTX2RYASgoBygus6ytm5AtzPw8sEeuOkjwUE1coEBuR0twEGV4M4zp4NrNkT14Q9OC9Pr91oEyo58mVYI0wboNKAA)

I get the following error with the code below:

```sh
TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type '{ color: "blue" | "red" | "white"; } | { variant: "wedge" | "putter"; }'.
  Property 'color' does not exist on type '{ variant: "wedge" | "putter"; }'.
```

```
type ProductGolfBall = {
  type: "golfball";
  options: {
    color: "blue" | "red" | "white";
  };
};

type ProductGolfClub = {
  type: "golfclub";
  options: {
    variant: "wedge" | "putter";
  };
};

type CartItem = ProductGolfBall | ProductGolfClub;
type CartItems = Array<CartItem>;

const cart: CartItems = [
  {
    type: "golfball",
    options: {
      color: "blue"
    }
  },
  {
    type: "golfclub",
    options: {
      variant: "wedge"
    }
  },
  {
    type: "golfclub",
    options: {
      variant: "putter"
    }
  }
];

const golfball = cart.find((item) => item.type === "golfball");

if (golfball) { // Check that it's truthy
  // According to typescript this can still be either ProductGolfClub or ProductGolfBall
  console.log(golfball.type)
  console.log(golfball.options.color) // Produces the TS2339 error above
}
```

Now I just don't see why the `golfball` variable can still be `ProductGolfClub` when the find operation only returns true for an array item where the `type` property is `golfball`.

I could just cast set the `golfball` variable as `ProductGolfBall`, but there must be some other way to have typescript understand what type the variable has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunetly TS is not able to make type guard from this case out of box. 
But you can make it manually by saying explicitly what the function will ensure, consider:

```
function isGolfBall(item: CartItem): item is ProductGolfBall {
    return item.type === "golfball";
}

const golfball = cart.find(isGolfBall)

if (golfball) { // Check that it's truthy
  console.log(golfball.type)
  console.log(golfball.options.color) // no error 
}
```

Most important is `:item is ProductGolfBall` it means that we explicitly say this function will be a type guard which will pass (return true) only for `ProductGolfBall`.

Inline solution will do also:

```
const golfball = cart.find((item): item is ProductGolfBall => item.type === "golfball")
```

Comment: I see. This seems to be called [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Since TS can not make a type guard automatically for this case, is there another way to write this code which would omit the need for a user defined type guard?

Comment: I don't think so. In general I see that readable and correct way to achieve what you need.